# I have ubuntu 18.04.3 on lenevo Ideapad 310. Network speed on hotspot created from it is less than 100kb/s

Tags: networking, drivers, lenovo, ethernet, hot-spot

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04.3 on my laptop and the network speed is slow compared to Windows for wired connection and the hotspot created from it gives speed less than 100kb/s.

I am using
"RTL8821AE" drive for wireless connection.
"RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller" for wired connection.